# C++ - STD regex crashes in MSVC during long multiline match

Tags: c++, regex, std

I am trying to extract `/* ... */` style comments from source files using std::regex. But "regex_search" sometimes crashes (unhandled exception) on long matches spanning multiple lines.

**STD example (not working)**

This example crashes for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string in = "/*\naaa\naaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaa\n*/";
    std::regex e(".*/\\*(\n|.)*?\\*/");
    std::smatch m;

    while (std::regex_search(in, m, e))
    {
        std::cout << m[0].str() << std::endl;

        in = m.suffix();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013 so this could be a compiler specific issue.

**Edit**: As @T.C. pointed out in the comments, the code works under [GCC 4.9](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/g86Ey1y8rDC36Sij), and it throws a stack overflow exception. It might only be a problem with the Visual C++ compiler only, or it could simply be that GCC allocates a bigger stack.

**Qt example (working)**

I tried implementing the same thing in Qt with no problem, so I do not think I've made any mistakes. But I would very much like to not rely on any external libraries.

```
QRegularExpression re(".*/\\*(\n|.)*?\\*/");
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator it = re.globalMatch(QString(in.c_str()));
while (it.hasNext())
{
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = it.next();
    QString word = match.captured(0);
}
```

**Question**

Is this possibly a bug in the std::regex implementation? Have I made a mistake anywhere?

Comment: Works for me (clang++ on OS X). However, the regex `"/\\*(\n|.)*\\*/"` should do the same, am I wrong?

Comment: @tnull The first `.*` of the expression is not important to the example, but I used it because I wanted to catch the indention level of the comment. And if I skip the `?` part then I think it would capture multiple comments such as `/* ... */ /* ... */` as a single huge comment.

Comment: ideone's GCC (4.8) has no usable `<regex>` support, so what you see is unsurprising. Your code [appears to behave correctly with GCC 4.9](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/g86Ey1y8rDC36Sij).

Comment: @T.C I see, I will remove my link to ideone from the question then, as it is misleading.

Comment: My VS2013 is crashing with a stack overflow in debug mode, or with an `regex_error` with the error code `std::regex_constants::error_complexity` on release mode

Answer (score 3):

I think it isn't a compiler problem (if you don't use gcc < 4.9). The regex crash because the amount of steps to obtain a result is too high. Try to do the same with this pattern:

```
/\\*[\\s\\S]*?\\*/
```

or with this one that emulates a [possessive quantifier](http://regular-expressions.info/possessive.html):

```
/\\*(?=((?:[^*]+|\\*(?!/))*))\\1\\*/
```

*(These two patterns are designed to work with the ECMAScript mode, that is, if I am not wrong, the default mode of your regex engine)*

**about your original pattern:**

The first mistake is to begin your pattern with `.*` *(that is not needed since you use the `regex_search` method)*. Since the quantifier is by default greedy, this first subpattern will match all characters until the end of each line. After to obtain a match the regex engine needs to backtrack character by character until it finds a `/*` in the string *(note that if you have several `/*` in the same line, only the last will be found)*.

The second mistake is to use something like `(\\n|.)*?` to describe all characters until what follows (i.e. `*/`).

Using this kind of construct have several costs:

- you use a capture group, so you pay the cost of the storage of each characters (one by one).
- you paid the cost of the alternation, because most of the time `.` will match and `\\n` is tested for nothing *(however, it depends how your comments look like, but writing `(?:.|\\n)*?` may be more performant.)*
- the most important cost is probably the fact you use a group with a non-greedy quantifier, because it forces the regex engine for all characters to enter the group and to leave the group for each character. *Without the lazy quantifier, in some regex engine `(?:a)+` can be 150 times slower than `a+`*

About the question you ask in comments, I will give you a general answer.

Yes, the amount of steps or backtracking steps is limited somewhere. If the regex engine is smart enough, it may detect during a pre-analysis that a pattern will cause too much work before trying to do something, but it's not always the case.

To know exactly what happens, you can put your regex pattern in a try/catch block, and check these two errors:

```
if (e.code() == std::regex_constants::error_complexity)
    std::cerr << "The complexity of an attempted match against a regular expression exceeded a pre-set level.\n";
else if (e.code() == std::regex_constants::error_stack)
    std::cerr << "There was insufficient memory to determine whether the regular expression could match the specified character sequence.\n";
```

Comment: I will have to look into your suggestion. However, how can "the amount of steps to obtain a result" become to high? Is the implementation using a fixed size buffer. Is there any way to know the limit?

Comment: There is still a library bug, in that the standard doesn't allow the implementation to crash (with a stack overflow). It should throw a `regex_error` and allow the user to recover.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I learned a lot about regex in the process reading it. However, while ´\\S´ works at capturing "new line" on for example http://regexpal.com/ it does not appear to do so in the STD implementation, and your emulated possessive quantifier still causes the "stack overflow exception" as mentioned by @T.C.. Also the pattern does not appear to throw any "std::regex_error" (even though it probably should throw something with "insufficient memory") so it was a bit of a red herring. But I will be sure to use non-capturing groups from now on to increase performance.

Comment: But in short, there still seems to be no way of matching the patterns that I want using STD and using the Visual Studio 2013 compiler as your first solution does not capture multiline comments, and your second solution causes the same stack overflow exception as my first solution.

Comment: Although I do not mention it in the example the reason that I start the pattern with ´/*´ is that I want to find out at which indention level the comment is at, so I would probably still need it, even though it is unfortunate it might capture multiple comments as well as code not part of the comment.

Comment: As mentioned I learned a lot about optimizing my regular expression from you answer. But I'm still a little bit confused. Do you think I've used regex wrong, or do you agree that using, mine or your second solution should not result in a stack overflow exception?

Comment: @Adelost: The second pattern (as the first) works well, you have probably missed something or it's due to the gcc version. Check these links: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/75n3Q9Bj1mjWEKsq  http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MhHY37bmq1lHf8Cl In my opinion the second is, from far more efficient, in particular when the pattern must fail (if `*/` is missing for example).

Comment: @Adelost: to be more clear, `\\S` is a shorthand character class that contains all characters that are not whitespaces. `\\s` contains all whitespaces (including the newline character.)

Comment: @Adelost: If you do not have access to a >4.9 gcc version and you choose to use QT or boost in perl mode, you can use: `/\\*(?:[^*]+|\\*(?!/))*+\\*/` *(so, the possessive quantifier directly)*

Comment: I don't think I've missed anything. I agree that your solution is probably far more efficient. But look, the thing is, my "STD example" as well as your "second example" throws a stack overflow exception in VS2013. But under GCC your solutions, as well as my original solution "works". This is my original solution under GCC: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/kQD0Gbpfl1vG97su

Comment: Also consider your first solution. On GCC the following code returns 4 matches, but on my computer running the same code in Visual Studio it only returns 2 matches:
http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wAPcLky80s9SzAkL

Your probably right that "line break" usually is matches with `\w`. But if you try it on a site such as "http://regexpal.com/" it instead appears that the "line break" belongs to `\W` instead, so it does not appear to be a strict standard.

I think we both can agree that it seems to be a problem with the MSVC2013 compiler. :)

Comment: But there is still the question if the GCC version of regex_search is implemented completely different from the Microsoft C++ version or, if the GCC version would also crash if it had a smaller allocated stack.

Comment: @Adelost: it is a "strict standard", you have mixed `\\s` and `\\w` in your head, the only difference you can see between languages and modes is the support (or not) of unicode characters. Take a look here for the most common shorthand character classes: http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html . I don't know the compiler from microsoft but it's possible that it doesn't handle some negated shorthand classes like `\\S`. So it ignores the backslashes and see the `S` as a literal.

Comment: Oups ny bad! I misswrote `\W` i meant to write `\S`. But I was not mistaken. If you write `[\S]*` on "regexpal" it will match anything not a white space (including "line break"). But on closer inspection it also appears that writing `[\s]*` matches all white space (including "line break") in your example, so perhaps you can see why I was confused.

Comment: I would never attempt to access match container by index without checking on whether it is empty or not. Yes, regex specs say if regex_search returns true it should not be empty but examples iterate smatch watching smatch.size(): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search

Comment: @AlexanderVX Thanks AlexanderVX, it might be good to be aware of, but the exception is thrown at "regex_search" so it cannot be part of the real problem.

Comment: @Adelost how about to print out the actual exception message: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_error/ I mean to catch it and analyse what's in there.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I now noticed another inconsistency under Microsoft C++. If i write the expression as `[\\s\\S]` it completely ignores the `\s` part, but if I rewrite it as `(?:\\s|\\S)` it works fine and I receive both " " and "\n" characters! So it appears that the backslash is not ignored, but there definitely seems to be some strange things under the hood in the compiler.

Comment: @AlexanderVX Strangely I'm not able to catch the exception not even `catch (...)` has any effect. Perhaps it's not possible to recover from a overflow exception? The full error message if you would be interested is the following `Unhandled exception at 0x76EEDDB3 (ntdll.dll) in UnitTests.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00652FF4)`.

Comment: Stack overflow, I see.

Answer (score 1):

Heh. I have been having the same problem recently with my static analysis code. So here is the solution, although it does rely on a 3rd party library (mine):

```
// http://www.benhanson.net/lexertl.html
#include <lexertl/generator.hpp>
#include <lexertl/iterator.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string in = "/*\naaa\naaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaa\n*/";
    lexertl::rules rules;
    lexertl::state_machine sm;

    rules.push("[/][*](\n|.)*?[*][/]", 1);
    rules.push(".|\n", rules.skip());
    lexertl::generator::build(rules, sm);

    lexertl::citerator iter(in.c_str(), in.c_str() + in.size(), sm);
    lexertl::citerator end;

    for (; iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << iter->str() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've also noticed that `std::regex e(".*/\\*[\\x00-\\xff]*?\\*/");` works too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with multiple simple regex. Sometimes they worked, sometimes crashed the application. Rexex objects where allocated on the stack for sloppy coding. I suspected low stack.

Then I allocated the regex objects with the `new()` constructor. For example:

`std::regex* myregexp = new std::regex("abc");`
and/or
`std::smatch* m = new std::smatch();` etc.. Only pointers where local.

This way worked for me under GCC and Linux. Today's PC are plenty of memory.

`Try` and `Catch` coding may help to handle the situation.

Of course, if you are regex-ing on an Arduino platform (very small memory device), you may have many troubles...